# In Cassandra how do I connect to only the nearby datacenter in a nation-wide cluster?

Tags: cassandra

Say I have a Cassandra cluster with 3 datacenters, 1 in Beijiing, 1 in Changsha, and 1 in Shenzhen, now I want my client application running in Changsha only talk to C* nodes in Changsha, How do I do?
Currently with the following code my client app is talking to all nodes in all datacenters in 3 cities, consequently the overall performance is drawn down by the latency between cities.

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.{Session, Cluster}

val cluster: Cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints("10.10.11.71")
    .withRetryPolicy(DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy.INSTANCE)
    .withReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(100L))
    .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new RoundRobinPolicy)
    .build()
val session: Session = cluster.connect()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the Load balancing Policy. Round Robin has the behaviour you have described in your question. You should use the [DC Aware Round Robin Policy](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/index.html?com/datastax/driver/core/policies/DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.html). That will use the nearest data center but all the nodes. It is also possible to use a [whitelist of nodes](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/WhiteListPolicy.html).